# is it possible to send a sms from my java application

Tags: java

is it possible to send a sms from my java application? which api should i use? 
I dont want to program in j2me..just in java or j2ee

Answer (score 1):

Try [SMSJ](http://smsj.sourceforge.net/).

Alternatively use an email to sms gateway. Then you can use Javamail to [send the email](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-send-an-email-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

[Googling returns one forum thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=150292) with several answers..